# PostgreSQL: create view everytime a table is updated

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-14

I'm new to Postgresql 14; I am trying to create a trigger on a table that creates a view every time the table is modified by INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE. After applying the trigger I am getting this error when trying to update/insert/delete anything in my table:

> ERROR:  control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN;
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function createmyview();
> SQL state: 2F005

I am assuming my trigger function is missing something...

This is my trigger function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION createmyVIEW() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    DROP VIEW IF EXISTS public.myVIEW; 

    CREATE VIEW public.myVIEW AS

    SELECT * FROM data.mytable;
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Applying the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER syncView AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON data.mytable
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE createmyView();
```

Comment: Why do you want to re-create a view on every data change? The view will automatically reflect changes in the underlying tables when they are modified.

Comment: You're right! I was not aware not of that... Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try Using 'RETURN' in the function, like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION createmyVIEW() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  DROP VIEW IF EXISTS public.myVIEW; 
  CREATE VIEW public.myVIEW AS
  SELECT * FROM data.mytable;
RETURN NULL;
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER;
```